# Как сделать универсальное движение для слона?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте . Есть класс слон , унаследованный от абстрактного класса фигура. 
 Как сделать универсальное движение не привязанное к конкретным фигурам? 
Можно писать собственные методы . Сам не решил , но не правильно . Мыслей нет как сделать пока что. Хотя бы в какую сторону двигаться подскажите пожалуйста.

```
public class Elephant extends Figure {
    public Elephant(Cell position) {
        super(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Cell[] way(Cell source, Cell dest) throws ImposibleMoveException, OccupiedWayException { // метод проверяет может ли фигура двигаться из точки source в точку dest . в случае успеха возвращает массив ячеек , который должна пройти фигура  . Либо  выкидывает исключения 

    }

    @Override
    public Figure copy(Cell dest) {
        return new Elephant(dest); // В случает возможности движения метод создает новый объект с конечными координатами 
    }
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то переопределить метод движения из класса фигура.

Comment: да только его надо сделать универсальным , не привязанным к конкретной фигуре

Comment: Я не понимаю вопрос. Универсальный - значит для всех или для многих. Вы хотите сделать универсальное движение у слона, тогда для каких целей?
Или сделать универсальное движение для всех наследников фигуры?

Comment: если я сам правильно понял , то универсальное движение для всех фигур . только как это ?

Comment: попросите того, кто дал Вам эту задачу, объяснить смысл слова "универсальный"

Comment: Делаете в классе Figure абстрактный метод move, в каждом наследнике фигуры реализовываете этот метод под нужды конкретной фигуры, для слона одна реализация хода, для короля(если вы делаете шахматы) другая, и так далее.

Comment: Максим а вы можете показать как его реализовать именно под фигуру слон ? Общая реализация

Comment: Скорее даже move будет одинаковый, а метод way будет рассчитывать путь конкретной фигуры. А вы гуглили алгоритмы, по моему есть много примеров в сети? В данный момент не могу код написать, часов через 6 смогу.

Comment: я искал в сети но ничего толкового не нашел . если не трудно напишите , как сможете алгоритм буду очень признателен вам

Comment: Из вопроса неясно что должно получиться в результате. Вам нужна реализация метода `way`? Как он вызывается? Что он должен делать?

Comment: есть комментарии в коде

Answer (score 2):

Определи метод "движение" в классе фигура, и по необходимости перегружай(переопределяй) его в определенных наследуемых классах через override. Потом создаешь Figure elephant = new Elephant();
Это даст абстракцию, которая позволит вызывать метод move, не зная, как конкретно он определён/переопределён.
Например, ты сможешь определить метод:

```
MoveNStepPositions(Figure figure, int steps){
 for(int i=0; i<steps;i++) 
    { 
      figure.Move(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Кирилл за код , но я это уже сделал ) мне надо было узнать , как именно сделать универсальный метод для фигуры слон . т.е метод Move(); Алгоритм